# Laravel 5 ubuntu apache issue

Tags: apache, ubuntu, linode

I'm stuck at annoying issue. I built a laravel application and I'm trying to install it in linode.com I'm using an apache server. I have my main website in there that is not a laravel website. So I want to use a subdomain. I have my domain dns managed through cloudflare. So I went to cloudflare I added an A record for my subdomain pointing to my server's public IP address. In apache I created a folder under /var/www/subdomain.domain.com I navigated to /etc/apache2/sites-available and created a virtualhost for my subdomain. I enabled the new subdomain virtualhost. restarted apache and all is working good. However, when I browse to http://mypublicipaddress I get redirected to subdomain.domain.com root folder of my subdomain not domain.com. Could anybody give me an idea of what's going on? I want my public ip address to go to domain.com but my subdomain to go to subdomain.domain.com

Thank you very much

Update: Here is my subdomain virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub.domain.com/public_html/laravel/public
</VirtualHost>
```

main site virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.domain.com/public_html/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can you share you conf files for both subdomain and main site

Comment: I just updated my post with conf files for both domains

Comment: you are visiting with your ipaddress ?

Comment: yes if I type my public ip address I get the subdomain root directory not my main website

Comment: try runing a2dissite first for subdomain then for main site. now enable your subdomain first by a2ensite then enable main site. does this help ?

Comment: public ip still points to subdomain. Maybe it's notmal that if you type the public ip address it should use the latest subdomain that was just added. I just want to make sure that my main website will stay working because cloudflare is caching everything. So I'm worried when the cache expires the main domain will redirect to subdomain like public ip does now

Comment: can you try by removing this line premanrntly ServerName www.domain.com. then restart apache

Comment: isn't that line important so when you type www.domain.com you get redirected to the right domain folder

Comment: no it's not important, by removing this we are telling apache to handle all requests with this virtual host and one specific request with subdomain.

Comment: Ok I will give it try

Comment: I tried removing ServerName www.domain.com restarted apache still the public ip is pointing to the subdomain instead of main domain

Comment: BTW if I type the main domain domain.com it works fine. Only when I browse using public ip that's when I get subdomain webpage